# Filter by values that have the exact names given in a list (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data.

```
> dat
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   id    name 
   <chr> <chr>
 1 1     a    
 2 1     b    
 3 1     a    
 4 2     a    
 5 2     b    
 6 2     c    
 7 2     b    
 8 3     a    
 9 3     b    
10 3     c    
11 3     d    
12 3     d
```

I would like to filter only by the following list

```
set <- NULL
set$names <- c("a","b","c")
```

The ids selected are those that contain exactly the names in the list.

So the result would be only the `2`s selected as follows:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   id    name 
   <chr> <chr>
 4 2     a    
 5 2     b    
 6 2     c    
 7 2     b
```

Here is the data for easy replication:

```
dat <- tribble(
  ~id, ~name,
  1, "a",
  1, "b",
  1, "a",
  2, "a",
  2, "b",
  2, "c",
  2, "b",
  3, "a",
  3, "b",
  3, "c",
  3, "d",
  3, "d"
)
```

I would like to have the following result.

Comment: Why would only the `2`s be selected?

Comment: @C.Braun I think because 2 only has exactly all the names i.e. "a","b","c". which is define for filtering.

Comment: that is correct. the `id` of 2 only has exactly all the names i.e. "a","b","c"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

`group_by(dat, id) %>% filter(setequal(name, set$names))`

This filters out all groups where the name column and `set$names` do not contain the same elements, but allows duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it is what you want

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(set$name %in% name) & all(name %in%set$name))



# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id  name
  <dbl> <chr>
1     2     a
2     2     b
3     2     c
4     2     b
```

Comment: I should have added that the above is a toy example. In reality I have thousands of `id`s and I don't know before hand which ones ought to be selected. So `& id == 2` will not work.

Comment: @Alex I didn't understand what you wanted. I corrected, it should just work now